# ComponentDidMount Code Executing even after component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, es6-promise

Inside ComponentDidMount() we call an api periodically to get data. But the api is still getting called even after the component unmounts.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let { getItemHistoryData } = this.props;

    for (let i = 0; i < 25 && !this.props.is_synched; i++) {
        await wait(5000);
        getItemHistoryData();
    }
}


const wait = (ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

But even if the user moves to a different page, getItemHistoryData() action is getting called.

Comment: does the for loop ever stop? In other words does is_synched ever gets to be true? I'm just wondering because say if is_synched is one way or another always false, then you are looking at waiting something like 125 seconds immediately after your component is actually mounted. In this hypothetical case, if the user is moving to a different page, your loop is still executing and at least one setTimeout is on the go.

Comment: Yes, is_synched becomes true after some time in a normal usecase, when the user stays on the same page for some seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from the code above is that your loop is running till completion even if the component is unmounted. To address this particular case without making significant changes in your code you can use a boolean to track component unmount and use same in the loop condition to ensure that the loop exits on iteration which follows the unmount. Please note that this will still execute the pending task once after your component is unmounted.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let { getItemHistoryData } = this.props;

    for (let i = 0; i < 25 && !this.props.is_synched && !this.isUnmounted; i++) {
        await wait(5000);
        getItemHistoryData();
    }
}

async componentWillUnmount(){    
    this.isUnmounted = true;
}
```

If you want to prevent any further iterations, you can refactor your code to use *setInterval* and then cleanup using *clearInterval*. For most practical cases, the approach which I suggested above should suffice and will prevent refactoring of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refactor a bit your code...

You need to keep track of your `setTimeout` in order to stop it on the `componentWillUnmount()`

```
let t;
async componentDidMount() {
  let { getItemHistoryData } = this.props;

  t = setTimeout(getItemHistoryData(), 5000);
}


componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = null;
}

getItemHistoryData() {

   // Do the function's stuff here

   if(!this.props.is_synched){
      t = setTimeout(getItemHistoryData(), 5000);
   }

}
```

Do the stuff about `i < 25 && !this.props.is_synched` at the end of the `getItemHistoryData()` then call -or not- the setTimeout again

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount runs and is done with. But it had a promise which when fulfilled will call the callback inside the promise. That is done by the javascript engine. It has nothing to do with react.

Edit: Looks like the for loop does get executed completely, but blocks at `await`. So it creates a chain of promises rather than 25 promises all at once. Need to do more research. I though only for-of loop does that. Sorry for the misinformation.

This is what your code will looks like when converted to es5 [Converted code with Babel JS](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=%3E%201%25&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=FAYw9gdgzgLgBAdwIYEt4F44AoC2UCUc6AfHAN7BxVwBOApjAK40RwR0JwAKNYOKUOlnpQwAGwBudIqUEwAKihx0wjGMLqjJdADRw8-fAG5gAX2DAkUAJ4QQcAGaM7MFJH2oIWfBSoOwNNhiDHAoRHAADEahcAA8cABMAKzRKADUaT4W1NRIyGiIqOpJEaXGlDlw4NDidAB0YmAA5lgARAAyYGAADqEAXK06KOUV5mbAQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=)

Comment: That is true, it will wait for the pending promise. But that should happen only once not 25 times. I am confused there.

Comment: The for loops has created 25 promises for you. It doesn't get blocked at the `await`. Your code gets converted to something like this -  `for(i=0;i<25;i++) { setTimeoutPromise().then(getItemHistoryData) }`

Comment: I have to disagree, it doesn't create 25 promises right away

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: Please check this sample code if you have doubts.

https://jsfiddle.net/tabvc2yx/1/

Comment: I am just trying to help here. And clarify my doubts. Please chill a little.

Comment: M chilled bro :D . I am just saying that I don't think it will create 25 promises right way. I agree with what you were pointing about how promises work normally but here it will wait for one promise to get over and then only it wait for another.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that from your example. That it's creating nested promises. promise1.then(promise2).then(promise3).then(promise4)...

Comment: Sorry for snapping on you @PankajkumarPanigrahi :)

Comment: No problem :) . .

Answer (score 0):

I give you more option that i like to use

save in state:

```
 intervalId: null,
 intervalCounter: 0
```

and componentDidMount add:

```
const intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 5000, 25)
```

create a new function `timer`:

```
timer = async () => {
    if(this.state.intervalCounter <= 25){
        getItemHistoryData();
        this.setState({intervalCounter: this.state.intervalCounter + 1})
    } else {
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId); //clear
    }
}
```

and don't forget to clear the interval when the user leaves the screen:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
       clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
   }
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I've suggested but with interval instead of timeout ... Execpt that I don't think this gonna work ... After the first `clearInterval` happen ... It will never fire again !

Comment: It works well, i use it in a few official apps. i bring it from my code

Comment: After your `clearInterval` you must triger again `setInterval(this.timer, 5000)` to get the `getItemHistoryData()` triggered once again ....

Comment: My mistake you right, i didn't notice to loop, i edit my post - new it easier! :)